# Explain how this works and how to convert to constexpr

Tags: c++, macros

I read that it's best practice to use constexpr over macros, so I'm wondering why this is? Along with how can I convert this to use constexpr.

I tried by creating a template with 5 args. like this-

```
constexpr auto FUNC(t1 dll, t2 name, t3 callingret, t4 args, t5 address)
{

}
```

```
#define FUNCPTR(dll, name, callingret, args, address) \
    __declspec(naked) callingret dll##_##name##args \
    { \
        static DWORD f##dll##_##name = NULL; \
        if(f##dll##_##name == NULL) \
        { \
        __asm { pushad } \
        f##dll##_##name = Offset(address); \
        __asm { popad } \
        } \
        __asm jmp [f##dll##_##name] \
    }
```

Comment: Note that the function generated by the macro has arguments of only `args`... all the other stuff such as `address` will have to be passed as non-type template parameters.

Comment: That’s got a number of extensions, including inserted `asm`. It looks to me like an `inline` function?

Comment: For sure -- this macro creates a function, it doesn't act like one.

Comment: However, it also seems to be using stringify to form an identifier from the different elements. That’s inherently pre-processor tokenizing.

Comment: I'm not even convinced the macro works... the arguments should not be token-pasted into the name of the created function, they should expand to separate tokens.  The local variable doesn't need to use token pasting either, since it's in its own unique scope it doesn't need a unique name.

Comment: Okay, things like specifying the parameter and return types could become template parameters. You can’t token-paste the names, but you might have a macro wrapper just for that. In practice, I don’t think you want to generate `asm` blocks; more likely, you want to cast to a function pointer and call that.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, you can [use the DLLImport extension to rename a function imported from a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/specifying-an-entry-point).

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

typedef void* HWND;
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "MessageBoxA")]
extern "C" int MsgBox(
    HWND hWnd, String* lpText, String* lpCaption, unsigned int uType);
```

If you have the address, as the original code presumed you did, you can also initialize a function pointer, *e.g.*

```
const auto user32_MessageBox =
  (int(WINAPI *)( HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT )) address;
```

The exact types here would depend on where `address` came from.  For example, if you got the pointer from `LoadLibrary()` and [`GetProcAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress), then the address is returned from a system call at runtime.  Anything that depends on it cannot be `constexpr`.

Declaring the type of the address as a `DWORD` and using inline `asm` are completely non-portable.  The version above is only portable if the type of `address` is correct, but the method you use obtain the address ought to ensure that.

One thing that code does that cannot easily be done without a macro is to merge the parameters into an identifier.  This should not be necessary, however.  (As Ben Voight pointed out, there’s no need for the local variable in the function the macro expands to to have a unique name.)